# Назначение клавиш Emmet в Atom

Tags: atom, emmet

Не разворачивается аббревиатура плагина Emmet по нажатию горячих клавиш.
Назначено сочетание <kbd>Ctrl + E</kbd>, но в самом Atom'e это открывает строку поиска.

Пытался переназначить через `keymap.cson`, но результат нулевой.
Есть ли какие решение, кроме прописывания в `keymap`:

```
   'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="text html basic"]:not([mini])':
   'Tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

Можно ли переназначить горячие клавиши самого атома?

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел решение. Мне помог плагин переназначающий разворот аббревиатуры на <kbd>Shift + Space</kbd>

Плагин называется **Emmet-snippets-compatibility**